# Numpy choose shape mismatch

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy problem with choose. I would like to choose certain indices as decribed in array a from array b.

```
a
Out[54]: 
array([[3, 2, 2],
       [0, 0, 2]], dtype=int64)

b
Out[55]: 
array([[[  6.,   1.,   8.,   9.,   3.,   8.,   5.],
        [  6.,   1.,   5.,   8.,   2.,   2.,  10.],
        [  6.,   1.,   1.,   0.,   9.,   3.,   6.]],

       [[ 11.,   3.,   8.,   9.,   3.,   8.,   5.],
        [ 12.,   7.,   5.,   8.,   2.,   2.,  10.],
        [  8.,   9.,   1.,   0.,   9.,   3.,   6.]]])

np.choose(a,b)
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shap
```

In the documentation of numpy it says:
Choice arrays. a and all of the choices must be broadcastable to the same shape. If choices is itself an array (not recommended), then its outermost dimension (i.e., the one corresponding to choices.shape[0]) is taken as defining the “sequence”.

I see that it is not recommended to choose from a ndarray but is there an elegant numpy way to get this to work anyway? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Expected output is:

```
[[9,5,1], [11,12,1]]
```

Comment: It looks to me like the outermost dimension of `b` is 2, yet your values in `a` go up to 3.  What are you expecting to come out of your choose operation?

Comment: expected output is [[9,5,1], [11,12,1]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks you want to use `choose` to select values from the dimension of length 7 in `b` (which is sized (2,3,7)).  Your choosing array `a` will work for this, but only if the sequence dimension is the outermost dimension (as you quoted).  The outermost dimension in Numpy is the *first* dimension.  What you need to do, then, is roll `b` so that it has dimensions (7,2,3).

```
np.choose(a, np.rollaxis(b, 2, 0))
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that the outermost dimension in Numpy is the first dimension